# Call function when if value in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() changes

Tags: swift, variables, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I have a variable that become value from NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

```
var GiftCount = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("Gift") as! Int
```

And i have a function named setGiftCount()...

I need call this function when variable GiftCount has changed... How to do it?

Comment: Just add observer for NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification

Comment: Btw NSUserDefaults has a method called integerForKey

Comment: Please tell me ho to add observer for NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification

Comment: For those who are lost by @LeoDabus 's reply, it's now UserDefaults.didChangeNotification as of Swift3/iOS 10.

Comment: Here is SO answer how to use KVO with UserDefaults in Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54889233/1418981

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**First**

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "Gift", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
```

**Second**

```
deinit {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "Gift")
}
```

**Third**

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    setGiftCount()
}
```

Comment: This will result in unexpected behaviour if anything else is observed, either by self or a subclass. You should specify a `context` and branch on that.

Comment: @BenKennedy can you tell me where I can read up on that behavior, and how to properly use `context`? I'm looking at these docs, but I think it's missing whatever context you have. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412787-addobserver

Comment: @salem: NSHipster has a good article on KVO, and gives an example for how to define a unique `context` value: https://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/#correct-context-declarations It's several years old and pre-dates Swift, but the methods used in the example above are the same (Obj-C) ones, so `context` is germane.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was looking for. Thank you @BenKennedy!

Answer (score 14):

You can add an observer for NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification to your view controller:

adding:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userDefaultsDidChange), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

removing it:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and add the selector method:

```
func userDefaultsDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    // your code...   setGiftCount()
}
```

Comment: The difficulty here is that you don't know _which_ value has changed, only that one of them has. There is no `userInfo` passed with the notification, either.